# C++: factoring the dispatch to a templated member function based on an enum

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code, where I am trying to factor out a `switch` statement which converts an `enum` to a templated function call.

I managed to get it working by introducing a helper class, but the result is not very simple or pretty.

Can you think of a more elegant solution?

```
#include <iostream>

enum Type {kA, kB};

struct A {
    static void process(int arg) { std::cerr << "A::process(" << arg << ")\n"; }
};

struct B {
    static void process(int arg) { std::cerr << "B::process(" << arg << ")\n"; }
};

// This is the original struct which contains the switch statement.
// However I have several such classes and methods, so I would like to
// factor out the switch().
struct S1 {
    template <typename T> void templated_func(int arg) {
        T::process(arg + 10 + i_);
        T::process(arg + 20 + i_);
    }
    void func(Type type, int arg) {
        switch (type) {
         case kA:
            templated_func<A>(arg);
            break;
         case kB:
            templated_func<B>(arg);
            break;
        }
    }
    int i_ = 100;
};


// This function call dispatches to a templated helper class based
// on the value of the enum type.
template <template <typename T> class HelperClass, typename... Args>
void dispatch(Type type, Args&&... args) {
    switch (type) {
     case kA:
        HelperClass<A>::method(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        break;
     case kB:
        HelperClass<B>::method(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        break;
    }
}

// It works but the result is not simple or pretty.  Can it be made simpler somehow?
struct S2 {
    template <typename T> void templated_func(int arg) {
        T::process(arg + 10 + i_);
        T::process(arg + 20 + i_);
    }
    template <typename T> struct Helper_func {
        static void method(S2* pthis, int arg) {
            pthis->templated_func<T>(arg);
        }
    };
    void func(Type type, int arg) {
        dispatch<S2::Helper_func>(type, this, arg);
    }
    int i_ = 100;
};

int main() {
    S1 s1;
    s1.func(kA, 1);             // prints A::process(111), A::process(121)
    S2 s2;
    s2.func(kB, 2);             // prints B::process(112), B::process(122)
}
```

Comment: Any answer to this is going to be ugly somewhere simply because it is translating run-time knowledge into the choice of a compile-time implementation. It can be done such that the final using code is not ugly but that gemnnerally akes the underlying implementation far worse.

Comment: The more elegant solution is to build a const array of pointers to functions, with each array cell holding a pointer to an appropriate templated function instance. This is a classic vararg template trick, much discussed elsewhere (including this very site).

Comment: The "const array of pointers to functions" would work for the dispatch of a single templated method.  The intent here is to write a templated dispatch function that is reusable across several templated methods.